# put coma on every 3rd number like in calculator. objective-c

Tags: objective-c, split, numbers, calculator

I have random number for example: 85769038
And need to receive 85,769,038
need to put coma like in calculator to split every 3rd number from back

Please wright a full code for these case with first string with numbers 85769038 and ending NSLog  to receive in console 85,769,038
This method must be universal for any quantity of numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NSNumberFormatter`

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
NSString *ft = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:85769038]];

[ft release];
```

Comment: Please wright a full code for these case with first string with numbers 85769038 and ending NSLog to receive in console 85,769,038 This method must be universal for any quantity of numbers